# Base R Legend "bg" parameter not working, ablines showing

Tags: r, plot

I am making a plot in base R and am having trouble making the legend opaque to hide some horizontal ablines in the background. I started with white and have tried all kinds of colors, but the background never changes. I have also tried the box.[i] family of commands, but no luck. The legend command is below, and if it matters, I am using plotrix. Am I missing something painfully obvious? Any advice would be sincerely appreciated, and thanks!

```
legend("topright", title="Treatment Modality", 
legend=c("PCI", "Medical Management"), pch=c(16,15), col=c("black","red"), bg="white")
```

Comment: Maybe your `par`s are messed up, can you run `graphics.off()` and try again without setting any `par`s?

Comment: Could you please also show your `plot` statement?